# How do I call a protected web api from a angular application

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-angular

I followed this doc: [asp.net core web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-web-api) and this [doc for the SPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code#acquire-a-token)

However, when trying to make a web api call from my angular application (with the [authorize] attribute set) I receive the following error message in the console log:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/api/getcustomer' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I'm able to successfully login to azure AD. However the Authorization header is missing from my api calls. I'm running the SPA in node/express. asp.net-core is backend.

I didn't create a separate app registration for the api. I did select, however to expose the api and created a scope.

401 is the status code: Not authorized.

Answer (score 0):

This error says that you must add a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to the HTTP response on the backend side.

For localhost, it would be `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=http://localhost:4200`.

Read about CORS for more information.

Comment: I edited orginal post to include 401 return code 'Not Authorized' Looks like thats a second item in console log. I think it's because the authorization header is not present in my api calls. How's MS's documentation says that angular & installed libraries will add it automatically.